# Is there any way to find special characters in string

Tags: gremlin

I have a requirement to perform different operations if string contains any special character.
Is there any way to implement regular expression in gremlin.

```
Input_Name= Test#input

if Input_Name.contains( "#/$%...") 
{
println " error "
}
else 
{
println "sucess"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently the Gremlin language does not have a `TextP.regex` predicate. Some implementations, such as JanusGraph, do add custom regex extensions to Gremlin. You could also, if the database you are using allows it, use Groovy closure syntax to include a regex in a query. Within the TinkerPop community we are planning to add a `TextP.regex` to the Gremlin language. The code is written and on a branch that we hope will be part of the TinkerPop 3.6.0 release if all goes well.

However, in your case, perhaps the existing `TextP.containing` could be used if there are a finite set of special characters you are looking for but it is likely not the most optimal way to solve the problem as you will have to `or` several `has` steps together.

Another option might be to use an external index if your database implementation supports that.

Just as an example of the closure syntax, if your implementation allows it, a REGEX match would look like the example below. In general though, use of closures is not recommended, and many implementations either fully block or extremely limit their use.

```java
gremlin> g.V().limit(20).filter {it.get().values('desc').next() ==~ "[A-Za-z]* [A-Z]'(.*)"}.values('desc')
==>Chicago O'Hare International Airport
```

**Updated 2023-03-23**

Starting with Apache TinkerPop version 3.6.0, the Gremlin language does now have a `TextP.regex` predicate. You can [read more details here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#a-note-on-predicates).

This allows you to write queries such as:

```java
g.V().has('desc',regex("[A-Za-z]* [A-Z]'(.*)")).limit(1).values('desc')
```